# Why is TemplateName property on MpnsTemplateRegistrationDescription undocumented on MSDN?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Notification Hubs with the Windows Azure Service Bus .NET SDK version 2.2.4.
I'm creating a templated MPNS registration like this:

```
var reg = await _hub.CreateMpnsTemplateRegistrationAsync(deviceToken, MPNS_TILE_TEMPLATE);
reg.TemplateName = "tile";
await _hub.UpdateRegistrationAsync(reg);

var theReg = await _hub.GetRegistrationAsync<MpnsTemplateRegistrationDescription>(reg.RegistrationId);
var tn = theReg.TemplateName; // this is null
```

However, TemplateName is always null.

Also, it appears that the TemplateName property is, itself, undocumented in the MSDN reference docs, except for on the "Registration Management" overview page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn530747.aspx

Any ideas?
thanks
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in .NET SDK. A bugfix has been release in version 2.2.6.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/2.2.6

Comment: Thanks. You guys have lots of documentation about developing mobile apps with Push notifications using Sencha and Cordova. Cordova does not really work. The PushPlugin is not supported in Windows Phone. All kinds of other Cordova issues too. Thought I'd let you know. Thx

Comment: We are already working to improve the integration with Cordova. We will have much better support soon.

Comment: I recommend anyone who goes near Cordova to thoroughly check out the quality of it before diving in.  It's been appalling for me and ill-documented.  For example, on iOS, check out the status bar plugin for iOS, then put focus in a textbox, then put focus somewhere else outside the textbox. The UI shifts -20px on y-axis, then eventually corrects after a while. This is one example or many other problems.  I'm surprised anyone is wasting their time with this.  We wasted £8,000 and 5 weeks before going completely native.